# How do you access the raw public data for a blockchain and then read the transaction ledger from it?

Tags: blockchain

For an arbitrary blockchain (ie not BTC, ETH), is there someplace to look for general information about where the publicly available raw blockchain data is... publicly available?  And how to read it?  EG in order to perform analytics on the transactions.

Thanks